# On a step of a proof of Van Kampen's theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

There is a little step on the proof of Van Kampen's theorem that I am missing. I will adapt the argument so that I can expose my problem as an isolated exercise:

Let $\omega$ and $\eta$ be two paths along a topological space $X$ which join a point $x$ to a point $y$. Suppose $X=U\cup V$ where $U$, $V$ and $U\cap V$ are path-connected open subsets. Suppose that $\omega$ and $\eta$ are path homotopic and let $F:\left [0,1\right ]\times \left [0,1\right ]\to X$ such that $F\left (s,0\right )=\omega \left (s\right )$, $F\left (s,1\right )=\eta \left (s\right )$, $F\left (0,t\right )=x$ and $F\left (1,t\right )=y$.

Suppose also that there exists a partition $0=t_0<\cdots <t_n=1$ of $I=\left [0,1\right ]$ such that if $I_i=\left [t_{i-1},t_i\right ]$ then $F\left (I_i\times I\right )$ is contained either in $U$ or $V$.

For every $i$ let $u_i:I\to \left [t_{i-1},t_i\right ]$ such that $u_i\left (s\right )=\left (1-s\right )t_{i-1}+st_i$ and call $\omega_i:=\omega \circ u_i$, $\eta_i:=\eta\circ u_i$. Also, define $\beta_i:I\to X$ such that $\beta_i\left (t\right )=F\left (t_i,t\right )$. We have to prove that $\left [\beta_{i-1}\ast \eta_i\right ]=\left [\omega_i\ast \beta_i\right ]$ as paths either in $U$ or $V$.

I really do not know how to prove it, nor even how to begin. I tried defining $H\left (s,t\right )=F\left (u_i\left (s\right ),t\right )$. Observe that $H\left (s,0\right )=\omega_i\left (s\right )$, therefore a path homotopy between $\beta_{i-1}\ast \eta_i$ and $\omega_i\ast \beta_i$ should (maybe) be defined as $G\left (s,t\right )=H\left (2s,t\right )$ for $s\leq \frac{1}{2}$. But I do not know how to completely define $G$, nor whether this is the correct way to define the first part of the homotopy. How would you prove the assertion?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your subdivision arguments involve only paths,   whereas to deal with homotopies you need to subdivide a square into little squares, each of which lies in either $U,V$, or both, and then join images of the vertices  of this subdivision in $X$ to base points staying in either $U,V$ or $U \cap V$, by the connectivity assumption. Then the whole square has to be deformed to a subdivided square in which each small square is mapped to $U$ or $V$ and all vertices to base points.

More details are in [this paper](http://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/brown-razak.pdf), and background also in [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019357717300460).